# Website with expired certificate not allowing to click on textbox in chrome browser, for the first load of website

Tags: html, input, autofocus

If i clear history of chrome browser and load a page, how's certificate is expired.
So the page is loaded for first time in the browser with expired certificate.

I can click on input box and type text in it, but the cursor is not showing.
The cursor shows if i change the tab or switch to another application and come back to the browser.

This issue observed only for the first load of page without any previous browser history and expired certificate.
If i want to observe this issue again, i have to clean browser history and reload the page or open it into incognito mode.

Issue observed in Chrome browser Version 59.0.3071.115 only.
It is working fine in older versions of Chrome browser.
The code is writing in jsp and running using java eclipse (tomcat).

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <input>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi, you've forgot to post your code :)

Comment: Code is

<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <input autofocus>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: please edit your question and take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask or answer questions and to learn more about how stackoverflow works.